# How to create latest backup file every time in ansible using time stamp. How to copy the latest file(same file to destination)

Tags: ansible

I have a use case i want to create a backup file with latest time stamp and then I want to copy the same/latest back up file to destination.(I was using `item` and `with_items` for that). But `ansible` overriding the existing backup file and creating new file with same time stamp. When I copy the latest backup file it is not moving to destination because same time stamp file already exists.

```
---    
# understanding with_items for correct syntax        
- name: create a back up file         
  file:        
    path: /test/backup_path/backup_{{ansible_date_time.date}}.bkp    
    state: touch    
    mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r    

- name: get the latest back up file    
  shell: ls -1t /test/backup_path | head -1    
  register: latest_bkp    
- debug: msg="{{ latest_bkp.stdout_lines }}"    

- name: Copy the latest file to restore path    
  copy:    
    src: /test/backup_path/{{ item }}    
    dest: /test/restore_path/    
    remote_src: yes     
    owner: root    
    group: root     
    mode: '0644'    
    force: yes    
  with_items: "{{ latest_bkp.stdout_lines }}"
```

My target node output

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -alrt  /test/backup_path/    
total 0    
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Aug 19 17:33 backup1    
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Aug 19 17:34 backup2    
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 59 Aug 19 18:03 ..    
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 65 Aug 19 18:49 .    
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Aug 19 19:07 backup_2019-08-19.bkp    

[root@localhost ~]# ls -alrt /test/restore_path/    
total 0    
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Aug 19 17:34 backup2    
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 59 Aug 19 18:03 ..    
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Aug 19 18:49 backup_2019-08-19.bkp    
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 50 Aug 19 18:49 .
```

Comment: My ultimate target is creating a back up file with time stamp and transferring the same file to destination

Comment: The above is playbook is working but at the time of back up file creation new backup file is not created. It is overriding the existing. When i transfer backup file transfer is not happens because already a backup file is present with the same time stamp

Answer (score 1):

> My ultimate target is creating a back up file with time stamp and transferring the same file to destination

As I look in your example you create and copy empty none modified file and restart playbook some times.
In this case:
1) Ansible recreates source file in `/test/backup_path/` (touch the same file, but set some permissions). And its time stamp updates after every running playbook.

```
- name: create a back up file         
  file:        
    path: /test/backup_path/backup_{{ansible_date_time.date}}.bkp    
    state: touch    
    mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

2) Ansible will copy empty or none modified source file to `/test/restore_path/`**only at  first running playbook or when there is no same destination file (condition of Ansible Idempotency)**. For this reason time stamp of destination file didn't update after playbook restarting (there is older file with same content). Idempotency means you can be sure of a consistent state in your environment.

```
- name: Copy the latest file to restore path    
  copy:    
    src: /test/backup_path/{{ item }}    
    dest: /test/restore_path/    
    remote_src: yes     
    owner: root    
    group: root     
    mode: '0644'    
    force: yes    
  with_items: "{{ latest_bkp.stdout_lines }}"
```

Let's say I will add one new line `test` to source file. In this case content of file will be updated.

```
- name: create a back up file         
    file:        
      path: /test/backup_path/backup_{{ansible_date_time.date}}.bkp
      state: touch
      mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r    

- name: Add data to file
    lineinfile:
      path: /test/backup_path/backup_{{ansible_date_time.date}}.bkp
      line: test
```

After rerunning playbook (only one time) you can sure that source and destination file were updated and have same content and time stamp (note please it's idempotency too).

To resolve your issue you can use none idempotent module `Ansible` for copying file (note please it is not best practice).
For example:

**instead:**

```
- name: Copy the latest file to restore path    
  copy:    
    src: /test/backup_path/{{ item }}    
    dest: /test/restore_path/    
    remote_src: yes     
    owner: root    
    group: root     
    mode: '0644'    
    force: yes    
  with_items: "{{ latest_bkp.stdout_lines }}"
```

**just use:**

```
- name: Copy the latest file to restore path  
  shell: cp -rf /test/backup_path/{{ item }} /test/restore_path/{{ item }} 
  with_items: "{{ latest_bkp.stdout_lines }}" 

- name: Change file permissions
  file:
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
    path: /home/restore_path/{{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ latest_bkp.stdout_lines }}"
```